# Oly subset Group if element within a columns are all present within a list and nothing else in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as:

```
The_list=["A","B","D"]

Groups Values
G1     A
G1     B
G1     C
G1     D
G2     A
G2     B
G2     A
G2     D
G3     A
G3     D
G4     Z
G4     D
G4     E
G4     C
G5     A
G5     B
G5     D
```

And I would like only to subset `Groups` where `Values` element are all within `The_list`, and that not other element are within that group that are not present within `The_list`.

Here I should only subset then:

```
Groups Values
G2     A
G2     B
G2     A
G2     D
G5     A
G5     B
G5     D
```

So far I tried:

```
df.loc[df.Values.str.contains["A" & "B" & "D"].groupby(df.Groups)]
```

Comment: Learning opportunity: Evaluate this statement by itself `"A" & "B" & "D"`

Comment: howy ou are right, for such purpose I need to do the same separalty for each Letters thanks

Comment: According to the description of the problem, shouldn't  `G3`  also be included in the final output, since all its values ( `A` and `D`) belong to `The_list`.  Or am I misinterpreting and a group must have  **all** the values of `The_list`? Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on column `Groups` then check `set` each values of group with set `the_list` and return all rows that groups have True values:

```
The_list=["A","B","D"]
mask_rows = df.groupby('Groups')['Values'].transform(
    lambda x : set(x) == set(The_list)
)
print(df[mask_rows])
```

shorter answer with [Paul H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1552748/paul-h) with using [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) after groupby:

```
print(df.groupby("Groups").filter(lambda g: set(g["Values"]) == set(The_list)))
```

Output:

```
Groups Values
G2     A
G2     B
G2     A
G2     D
G5     A
G5     B
G5     D
```

Comment: Just a note: `.groupby(...).filter(...)` lets you skip the indexing (`df[mask_rows]`) step

Comment: @PaulH, thanks but i can not understand, can you explain more, with the `filter` we can use `regex` for selecting columns by name.

Comment: I'm saying that in your answer, using `.filter`, instead of `.transform` means `mask_rows` is the final answer. You don't need to do `df[mask_rows]` afterwards

Comment: More clearly: `result = df.groupby("Groups").filter(lambda g: set(g["Values"]) == set(magic_values))`

Comment: @PaulH, thanks, I check before you send a code but I always get an empty dataframe

Comment: I get your answer with that code (if you assign the output to a variable)

Answer (score 1):

Masking the values which belong the `The_list` first (here considered as a set named `values_set` for better performance), and only then determine the groups whose values are all should scale better than [I'mahdi's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72678074/17120692):

```
mask = (
    df.eval('Values in @values_set')
      .groupby(df['Groups'])
      .transform('all')
)

df[mask]
```

---

**Basic benchmark**

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Groups': ['G1', 'G1', 'G1', 'G1', 'G2', 'G2', 'G2', 'G2', 'G3', 'G3', 'G4', 'G4', 'G4', 'G4', 'G5', 'G5', 'G5'],
    'Values': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'Z', 'D', 'E', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'D']
})

values_set = {"A", "B", "D"}

n = 50_000

df = pd.concat([df]*n) # simulate a big dataset 

print(df.shape) # shape (850000, 2)
```

I'mahdi's solution:

(changed `set(The_list)` to `values_set` to be fair)

```
%%timeit -n 10

mask_rows = df.groupby('Groups')['Values'].transform(lambda x : set(x) == values_set)

df[mask_rows]

# Output: 357 ms ± 45.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Mine:

```
%%timeit -n 10

mask = (
    df.eval('Values in @values_set')
      .groupby(df['Groups'])
      .transform('all')
)
df[mask]

# Output: 138 ms ± 26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: thanks, I have a question, what does `@` do in eval?

Comment: @I'mahdi `@x` inside the eval query is [replaced by the object referenced by `x`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#local-variables)

Comment: G3 included in your result

Comment: @BENY I noticed, but thanks for the heads up. The description of the problem and OP's expected ouput are a little ambiguous regarding if G3 should be included or not. I asked OP for clarification

Answer (score 1):

Try with two step

```
out = df.groupby('Groups')['Values'].unique().map(tuple)==tuple(The_list)
out = df.loc[df.Groups.isin(out.index[out])]
Out[805]: 
   Groups Values
4      G2      A
5      G2      B
6      G2      A
7      G2      D
14     G5      A
15     G5      B
16     G5      D
```